# ComboBox added as a part of Visual Studio 2010 editor adornment doesn't change selection

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I'm working on the Visual Studio 2010 editor adornment extension. Since whole VS editor is WPF based, it is posible to add arbitary WPF component. When I add ComboBox to editor as new adornment, I can click on ComboBoxItem but ComboBox Selection won't change. Code looks like something like this:

```
var cbox = new ComboBox();
var cboxitem = new ComboBoxItem();
cboxitem.Content = "Item 1";
cbox.Items.Add(cboxitem);
var cboxitem2 = new ComboBoxItem();
cboxitem2.Content = "Item 2";
cbox.Items.Add(cboxitem2);

Canvas.SetLeft(cbox, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(cbox, _view.ViewportTop);
_adornmentLayer.AddAdornment(AdornmentPositioningBehavior.ViewportRelative, null, null, cbox, null);
```

Am I missing something?